# sqlite3 not installed error on apple-m1 (TypeOrmModule, NestJS project)

Tags: sqlite, nestjs, typeorm, apple-m1

I am getting error that sqlite3 is not installed, I am using apple m1 pro NestJS project with TypeOrm, of course sqlite3 package is present.

Not something I am usually working with, doing some Udemy course, so any help would be great!

Comment: did you manage to resolve this issue?